# Problems with race conditions on ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition

I got a multithreaded application in which n threads write to an `ConcurrentHashMap`. Another n Threads read from that Map and copy its Value to a copy List.
After that the original List is removed from the map.
For some reason I always get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

I even tried to create my own lock mechanism with a volatile boolean, but it won't work. When using **Google Guava** with `Lists.newLinkedList()` i get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. When using the StandardWay `new LinkedList(list)` I get an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Here is the compiling code example:

```
public class VolatileTest {

public static Map<String, List<String>> logMessages = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();

public static AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Thread() {

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        if (!VolatileTest.lock.get()) {
          VolatileTest.lock.set(true);
          List<String> list = VolatileTest.logMessages.get("test");
          if (list != null) {
            List<String> copyList = Collections.synchronizedList(list);
            for (String string : copyList) {
              System.out.println(string);
            }
            VolatileTest.logMessages.remove("test");
          }
          VolatileTest.lock.set(false);
        }
      } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
  };
}.start();

new Thread() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      if (!VolatileTest.lock.get()) {
        VolatileTest.lock.set(true);
        List<String> list = VolatileTest.logMessages.get("test");
        if (list == null) {
          list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());
        }
        list.add("TestError");
        VolatileTest.logMessages.put("test", list);
        VolatileTest.lock.set(false);
      }
    }
  }
}.start();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ConcurrentModificationException because you have your locking broken and the reader thread reads the same list (by Iterator) the writer writes to at the same time.

Your code looks like a try of lock-free coding. If so, you must use **CAS** operation like this:

```
while (!VolatileTest.lock.compareAndSet(false, true) { } // or while (VolatileTest.lock.getAndSet(true)) {} - try to get lock
try {
    // code to execute under lock
} finally {
    VolatileTest.lock.set(false); // unlock
}
```

Your

```
if (!VolatileTest.lock.get()) {
      VolatileTest.lock.set(true);
      ...
}
```

is not atomic. Or you can use synchronized section or any other standard locking mechanism (ReadWriteLock, for instance)

Also, if you deal with a list for reading and writing using one lock, you don't have to use synchronized list then. And moreover, you don't need even ConcurrentHashMap.

So:

1. use one global lock and plain HashMap/ArrayList **OR**
2. remove your global lock, use ConcurrentHashMap and plain ArrayList with *synchronized* on each particular instance of the list **OR**
3. use a Queue (some BlockingQueue or ConcurrentLinkedQueue) instead of all of your current stuff **OR**
4. use something like Disruptor (http://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/) for inter-thread communication with many options. Also, here is a good example of how to build lock-free queues http://psy-lob-saw.blogspot.ru/2013/03/single-producerconsumer-lock-free-queue.html

Answer (score 0):

[ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is fail safe meaning you will not encounter `ConcurrentModificationException`. It's your `List<String>` within the map where one of your thread tries to read the data while other thread is trying to remove the data while iterating.

I would suggest, you don't try locking on whole map operation, but instead look out for making thread safe access to list may be using [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) or [SynchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)).

Also note, your entry condition `if (!VolatileTest.lock) {` for both the threads means they can both run at the same time as initially by default boolean would hold false value and both may try to work on same list at the same time.

Comment: Why do I have any problems at all, since I lock the complete write/read operations? (currently for test purpose)

Comment: Your locking pattern is not working, you'd need an atomic "check and set" operation on your boolean (see AtomicBoolean). Or a Lock, which serves the same purpose.

Comment: Hi, please see me edited code, I changed the volatile to AtomicBoolean. I also changed the List to SynchronizedList holding the LinkedList, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned the locking pattern does not look valid. It is better to use synchronized. The below code works for me

final Object obj = new Object();

and then

synchronized (obj){....}  instead of if (!VolatileTest.lock) {.....}

Comment: Hi, please see me edited code, I changed the volatile to AtomicBoolean. I also changed the List to SynchronizedList holding the LinkedList, still not working.

Comment: Switching the implementation of boolean in and of itself does not solve your issue, which is that anything can happen between the time a thread checks your `lock` boolean and the time you set to true the same boolean (which is what "your check and set is not atomic" means). I mentionned AtomicBoolean because it conceptually can solve the issue (with the `compareAndSet` method), but you'd have to use it properly. As @ramp suggests, the readable, efficient, concise, and least prone to error way of doing this is using Locks and/or syncrhonization.